# vb.Net & Access yes/no sql execution error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I am getting an sql execution error when I try run my query. I have in the Customers table a field called 'Hidden' which is a yes/no field. When I run my query However, it halts with 'sql execution error No value given for one or more parameters'.

I have have tried variations in my statement including: yes, -1,1,0 but nothing seems to work. What I need to achieve is if the Hidden field is ticked, It appears as tickbox in access, then run query. Where have I gone wrong. Thanks

```
SELECT        Code, Name, [Invoice address], [Invoice contact], [Contact tel], [Contact fax], [Contact e-mail], Balance
FROM            Customers
WHERE        (Hidden = -1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Name` is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) in Access SQL. You need to enclose it in square brackets like you have done with the other field names.

(Note that enclosing table and field names in square brackets never hurts, so when in doubt just go ahead and use them.)

Comment: Duh, just saw that. How did I miss that. Thanks